# How long is the authorization valid for my installed application

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api, installed-applications

In the developer console for Google API's I created a project with Google Calendar services enabled.
I want to create a Java application that connects to Google Calendar every 24hours (with a cron job).

Now I created the client Id with the pop-up, selected installed application, downloaded the JSON and my Java application works. Now I'm wondering how long will this JSON-file be valid? until I reset the client secret? It's an application that needs to run for several years every 24 hours without interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For future reference:**
If you use a "installed application" api client code. It keeps valid until you reset the client credentials in the console.